# Delete dynamically created objects

Tags: c++, memory, c++11

In my application I am creating and returning an array filled with dynamically allocated objects from a derived class like this:

```
void someGetter(std:vector<DerivedClass> & returnV)
{
    BaseClass* base = object->clone();  // "object" is a "unique_ptr<BaseClass>"

    DerivedClass* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*> (base);

    if (derived != nullptr)
    {
        returnV.push_back(*derived);
    }
    else
    {
        delete base;
    }
}
```

This obviously creates a memory leak (valgrinds helps me here) because derived is never deleted.

I have tried to free the allocated memory like this:

```
delete &returnV[0];
```

It doesn't give any compilation errors/warnings and the code still runs fine. but valgrind reports a few additional errors (invalid read, invalid free) on that line of code and the leak is still there.

Is there any way to free the memory returned like this? Or should i return unique_ptr's instead of the objects ?

Comment: Something inside me (as well as someone in the basement) screams "horrible abuse"... what if you have an `EvenMoreDerivedClass`? That'll be sliced up in the copy...

Comment: For a c++11 question: You really should use `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on your usage scenario). Manual memory management is really not to be recommended, since the potential of memory leaks (due to a missing `delete` like in your code, or due to not handling the case that an exception is thrown) is quite high. So my recommendation is never (as always there are some exceptions to that, although not many) to use manual management and always use smartpointers (or things like boost pointercontainers) instead.

Comment: @Grizzly with Kerrek's second answer i'm not doing manual memory management anymore

Comment: The point is not specific to this scenario, but more a general piece of advice that it is almost always better not to use manual memory management. For example in the project I'm working on a `clone` method returning a raw-pointer would not make it through code review, since that is considered to risky (the possibility of forgetting to `delete` is to high and there is no indication how the memory was actually allocated (is `delete` even correct, or would destructor-call followed by `free` or even something else be correct).

Comment: @Grizzly I always try to wrap my objects in `unique_ptr`'s. I am fairly new to c++11 though (I come from C, my latest project was c89) and I'm still sometimes struggling with the new move semantics, but I'm getting there. Using clone was suggested in another question on StackOverflow and no one told me it was bad practice (although I suspected something like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the design seems very questionable to me: You have at once a polymorphic hierarchy, and *also* a container that holds *values* of a specific member of that hierarchy. There's no end to the problems you're inviting. It would seem far more sensible to have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`.

Anyway, here's a moderately safe and efficient way to insert into the container only those objects whose dynamic type matches precisely. It assumes that every class in the hierarchy has an accessible copy constructor.

```
void someGetter(std:vector<DerivedClass> & returnV)
{
    if (typeid(*object) != typeid(DerivedClass)) { return; }

    returnV.insert(static_cast<DerivedClass&>(*object));
}
```

The semantics of this are slightly different from yours, because your code would allow the case where `*object` is of a strictly more derived type than `DerivedClass`, and the copying into the vector would *slice* the object. The present code does not suffer from this problem.

---

**Update (after your comment):** If `DerivedClass` is indeed `final` (and please mark it as such!), then the following does without `typeid`:

```
void someGetter(std:vector<DerivedClass> & returnV)
{
    if (DerivedClass * p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(object.get()))
    {
        assert(typeid(*p) == typeid(DerivedClass));   // beware of slicing!

        returnV.insert(*p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well at first i was using the unique_ptr's but my project coordinator asked me to get it into values. Wat exceptions are you trying to catch? why a static_cast?

Comment: you can assume DerivedClass will never be subclassed.

Comment: @Minion91: Sorry, the exception problem goes away if you let me use the copy constructor. If you insist on using `clone` (which is stupid if you also want value semantics), then you have to deal with exceptions.

Comment: I don't realy want `clone` i'm trying your suggestion atm

Comment: @Minion91: Updated with your new assumption. You can skip the `assert` line; I just put it in there for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to create a vector that holds *values* of type `Derived` then the code is correct except for the memory leak. Note that the object you need to free is not the one in the container (which is a copy) but rather the one that you cloned:

```
void someGetter(std:vector<DerivedClass>&  returnV)
{
    BaseClass* base = object->clone(); (object is a unique_ptr<BaseClass>)
    DerivedClass* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass> (base);
    if (derived != nullptr)
    {
        returnV.push_back(*derived);
    }
    delete base;
}
```

Additionally if `clone()` does what it says (i.e. it clones the object) then you can avoid the operation by first testing with `dynamic_cast` whether the `base` object *is* a `DerivedClass`. If it is then insert into the container the copy and avoid the cloning.

Comment: Clone does exactly what it says. so push_back automatically creats a copy of the object ? with the copy constructor ?

Comment: It would be even faster to do `typeid(*object) == typeid(DerivedClass)`, non? And safer, too, because it won't slice&dice your `EvenMoreDerivedClass`.

Comment: @Minion91: Yes, containers hold *values*, it will store one copy of your object using the copy constructor (in your case, in some other cases it might *move* in C++11, or construct in place... but at any rate the container will hold it's own copy of the objects passed in)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't like using `typeid` in general, so it does not pop to mind as a tool often. In this case, and because of the problem with slicing (if it is a problem) it might be worth using `typeid`. Regarding performance, my standpoint is that if RTTI is a performance bottleneck or even noticeable, the design of the application is wrong.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: But we're *already* using RTTI for the dynamic cast! Why make a copy that we never wanted in the first place, when we could have *known* that in advance?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: OK, fair enough - though that still leaves the slicing problem and the code will leak if there's an exception.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If the user follows the recommendation in the last paragraph, there will be **no** memory leak, as no memory is allocated. It removes the need for `clone()`: *Test the type, perform `dynamic_cast` and insert that*. No `clone`, no `new` no memory leak :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Can you give me an example on how to do it without the clone ? and Derived will never be derived again, so the slicing wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer - always delete base.

```
if (derived != nullptr)
{
    returnV.push_back(*derived);
}
delete base;
```

Vector takes a copy of derived - so clone object is not needed anymore.

[UPDATE]

**I hope you have virtual destructor in `BaseClass` - if not - then add it.**

**And one more warning:** it might happen that `base->clone()` returns something more derived than derived:

```
class MoreDerivedClass : public DerivedClass {};
```

Then this code succeed even if real class of base is `MoreDerivedClass`:

```
DerivedClass* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass> (base);
```

You can use `typeid()` to check real type of base...

---

**[UPDATE2]**
Consider to change a little your design - and keep clones of your base in vector of unique_ptr of DerivedClass:

```
void someGetter(std:vector<std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>> & returnV)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(base.get()) != nullptr)
    {
        returnV.push_back(dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(base->clone()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `push_back` uses the copy constructor. I think David is saying that your code should be

```
void someGetter(std:vector<DerivedClass>&  returnV)
{
    DerivedClass*derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(object.get());
    if (derived != nullptr)
        returnV.push_back(*derived);
}
```

avoiding the cloning and deleting altogether.

*Note added in edit:* We must not pass the pointer obtained from `unique_ptr<>.get()` on to any function which may potentially keep a copy, defying the whole point of `unique_ptr`. The above code doesn't do that.

Comment: Isn't using get kind of evil? It kinde beats the purpose of a unique_ptr no ?

Comment: @Minion91 **No** 1) If it was evil per se, it wouldn't be in the standard library. 2) here we are not leaking the pointer (which you can do with `.get()`), but merely use it as pointer, i.e. we pass it to a function that requires the actual pointer type.

Comment: Then where do you drat the line between evil and not? because you can certainly do some pretty evil stuff with unique_ptr.get()

Comment: simple: It's evil if you pass it to a "foreign" function, such as user-supplied code (or imported libraries). If you don't pass it on (such as here), that's perfectly safe. If you pass it on to your own (internal) routines, it gets murky, because those routines cannot guarantee  that they wouldn't keep a copy (not in the sense that `const` guarantees const-ness via control by the compiler), and you must rely on yourself without control by the compiler.